# How to maintain leading zeroes on binary conversions in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, binary

I want to convert a series of numbers < 1000 into binary to do some bitwise analysis in Excel

But the DEC2BIN function in Excel doesn't seem to allow me to specify leading zeroes for the smaller numbers. The BASE(x,2) functionn will handle the larger numvbers better than DEC2BIN, but still drops leading zeroes of the smaller numbers.

`=BASE(999,2)` returns 1111100111 but `=BASE(511,2)` returns 111111111

I would really like it to return 0111111111

Is it possible to do that in Excel?

Answer (score 2):

You can just specify the minimum number of digits when using [Base](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/base-function-2ef61411-aee9-4f29-a811-1c42456c6342) e.g.

```
=BASE(511,2,10)
```

[image]

Since your numbers are all less than 1000, 10 digits are sufficient.